# LTR bibliography in a RTL document

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, hebrew, right-to-left

I have a Lyx document in Hebrew(RTL Language), while all the sources are in English(LTR Language).
Therefore, I've added `\selectlanguage{english}` before the bibliography, and `\selectlanguage{hebrew}` in it's end. So now the bibliography looks good.

However, whenever I add a citation, it's number is inverted(a.k.a 31 instead of 13). Surrounding the citation with `\selectlanguage` tags works to fix the problem(although is quite cumbersome), but than the citation appears in the beggining of the line.

Any help please?

**EDIT1**: I have noticed that this becomes possible if you surround the citations with `\beginL` and `\endL`. However, if I do that, the parantheses surrounding the citation's number become inverted(a.k.a. ]12[ instead of [12]).

**EDIT2**: As to your questions.
Providing minimal working code is hard, as it's a lyx document, so it generates lots of noise. However, Here's the LaTeX preamble:

```
\usepackage{cite}
\let\oldcite\cite
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{\beginL\oldcite{#1}\endL}
```

I use ordinary \cite command for the citations with a basic bibtex bibliography.

Comment: A minimum working example would help.

Comment: I'd love to help, but need an example. I use Hebrew and Greek in LyX, myself.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided any information about how the citation commands are formed and if you use a citation management package. The following suggestion thus definitely constitutes a stab in the dark.

If the "only" problem that's left to solve is the reversed ordering of the square brackets, you could try loading the `cite` package and issuing the commands

```
\renewcommand\citeleft{[}
\renewcommand\citeright{]}
```

to fix it. If that doesn't help, try switching the arguments of `\citeleft` and `\citeright`.

Comment: Yeah, it is the only problem left. However, this doesn't work, didn't change anything.

Comment: @Svarog - from your second edit I see that you do use the `cite` package. Did you try both `\renewcommand\citeleft{[} \renewcommand\citeright{]}` and the reverse, i.e., `\renewcommand\citeleft{]} \renewcommand\citeright{[}`?

Comment: Yes. To make it even more clear, I tried with ordinary parentheses. I think latex is still using \cite from latex.ltx and not cite.sty, although I am using package cite